# How to return true if strpos is not exactly false?

Tags: php, codeigniter, strpos

I know how `strpos` works, and it is working as expected, but the return in the `if` function isn't.

Some code:

```
foreach ($socialstream as $key => $social) {
    //filtering in here
    $result= $this->search_objects($social);
    ....
}
```

My function search_objects:

```
function search_objects($objects)
{
    $filters = array('word', 'test');
    foreach ($objects as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
            $this->search_objects($value);
        } else {
            //look for faulty strings in value
            foreach ($filters as $filter) {
                if (!is_int($value) && strpos($value, $filter) !== false) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If I print out my `$result`, I always get `false` back, instead of the `true` in the `if` function. I know it gets to the `if` when the needle exists in the haystack, by debugging, it's just not returning it.

What am I missing?

Comment: Add `var_dump(!is_int($value) && strpos($value, $filter) !== false);` inside your second `foreach` and see what it outputs on each iteration.

Comment: Did you actually read my first comment? "not **a** var_dump()". Copy paste that exact command :)

Comment: Returns true if it exist, otherwise false. Is this what you expected it to do?

Comment: @Bananam00n What are you trying to do? If a single filter is found, it should return `false` right?

Comment: as soon as 1 word of the filter array exist, it should return true, and get out of the foreach, because there's no point to continue.

Comment: Consider adding an `array` type hint to your function for safety, i.e. `function search_objects(array $objects)`. That will kick out anything that isn't an array (presuming that is what you want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem has to do with the recursive part:

```
    if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
        $this->search_objects($value);
    }
```

You probably want to do something with the return value. Like:  `if ($this->search_objects($value)) return true;`

(Then again, I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish)

edit: Try this:

```
function search_objects($objects)
{
    $filters = array('word', 'test');
    foreach ($objects as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
            if ($this->search_objects($value)) {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            //look for faulty strings in value
            foreach ($filters as $filter) {
                if (!is_int($value) && strpos($value, $filter) !== false) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: the function is to remove posts which have - for example - curse words in them. so if there is a curse word in a post, the whole thing should not be shown. (instead of 'deleting' the word out of the post)

Comment: my point is that the recursive bit's result is completely ignored. if the outer function call finds a $value that is array or object, it will call the same function again (inner) with $value but when it returns, the outer function does nothing with the result. So it defaults to the 'return false' at the end of the function.

Comment: ooh, now I see what you did! thank you so much! :-) Can't believe I missed that.